# Dependencies aren't being included on the build output of electron forge

Tags: build, packaging, electron-forge

My electron app project uses `create-react-app` and my main process needed the `electron-devtools-installer` module. I'm using `electron-forge` for building the app. Now after running `npm run make` to package and built the app, I'm getting this error message

> Error: Cannot find module 'electron-devtools-installer'

after opening the app. I'm not getting this error when I simply run `electron .`, thus I suspect the module is not being included on the packaging.

Now the said module is for development only, I could simply write a logic to ignore it when in production mode but what happens when I really need a 3rd party modules in my main process in the production, so how do I include the dependencies modules in the packaging?

I moved the `electron-devtools-installer` mode in `dependencies` key in `package.json` but it still doesn't work.

My `package.json` contains:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "description": "some description",
  "main": "main/init.js",
  "author": "anonymouse",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"react-scripts start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
    "package": "react-scripts build && electron-forge package",
    "make": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make",
    "clean:winbuild": "rmdir build /s /q & rmdir out /s /q"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.67",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.67",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.67",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.67",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.67",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "electron": "^21.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": "./forge.config.js"
  }
}
```

My `forge.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    ignore: [
      /coverage.*/,
      /node_modules.*/,
      /public.*/,
      /src.*/,
      /\.env|\.gitignore|.*bak|eslint.*|package-lock.*|(?<!build.*)\.txt|(?<!build.*)\.md/
    ]
  },
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        name: 'bkkgapp'
      }
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip'
    }
  ]
}
```